# Browser inside my App - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, browser, uiwebview

I'm looking for a good Browser inside my App . That is I click a link in my app and instead of taking me to Safari it takes me to a UIWebView with some basic controls (back, forward, refresh, stop and maybe share). I could write one myself, but I'm sure there must be something already out there. I googled around and I couldn't find anything that wasn't going to be seriously deprecated. Any suggestions?

Comment: you havn't googled, definitely not.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own with `UIWebView` or use a library with built in functions like this one:
https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController

Answer (score 4):

You should create your own browser using `UIWebview` with the features you need.

Follow the tutorial [here](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tutorial-build-your-very-own-web-browser/).

Comment: Link is really dead

Answer (score 1):

take a UIWebView property and use the following code.

```
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    [_webVeiew loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UIWebView.

> [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Either implement your own solution using `UIWebView` or use a library that adds some custom features like [TSMiniWebBrowser](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSMiniWebBrowser).